# set the field Ownership a read only for a specific profile?

Tags: administration, user-management, user-admin, userrecordaccess

I have only 1 profile that i need to disable this option, as I dont want them to be able to change the ownership for: Accounts, Leads, Opportunity

But when i try to do it as I would do a different field, i dont have the option to select read only, is this because if the user creates a new one, the system will not be able to save this user as owner? if this is right the only way to restrict this will be with page layouts?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a validation rule:

```
AND($Profile.Name='Some Profile',ISCHANGED(OwnerId))
```

While they'll be taken to the change owner screen, as normal, when they to save the change, they'll be given an error message instead.

You could also use a trigger to prevent ownership change, or you could set up multiple page layouts (as you've already observed), but a validation rule or trigger is the only way to prevent *any* unauthorized access to changing ownership.

This validation rule will allow the user to still create records, as ISCHANGED appears to only work on updates.

Comment: Awesome, i didnt think in the idea of the validation, I think that is a better approach than creating multiples page layouts, i think in the long term having too many layouts can get painful to manage, Thank you!

Comment: @manza You're welcome. The best part about salesforce is there's usually more than one way to do something once you get to know all the features pretty good.